# data.frame error when trying to import data using FAOSTAT

Tags: r, package

I am trying to use the FAOSTAT package to download some data from the FAO database. I followed a tutorial here:
https://www.machinegurning.com/rstats/bubble_maps/

I also tried following the code in the vignette but get the same error.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FAOSTAT/vignettes/FAOSTAT.pdf

Here is the code used:

```
library(FAOSTAT)

apple_df <- data.frame(
  varName = c("areaHarvested", "yield", "extractionRate","production","seed"),
  domainCode = "QC",
  itemCode = 515,
  elementCode = c(5312,5419,5423,5510,5525),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

apple_df_lst <- with(
  apple_df,
  getFAOtoSYB(
    name = varName,
    domainCode = domainCode,
    itemCode = itemCode,
    elementCode = elementCode,
    useCHMT = TRUE,
    outputFormat = "long"
  )
)
```

So this should give me a data frame with the data extracted from FAO but instead I get these error messages:

```
(1): Downloading variable arableLand ... Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , var[i]) : undefined columns selected
[1] 1
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , var[i]) : undefined columns selected
[1] 2
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , var[i]) : undefined columns selected
[1] 3
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , var[i]) : undefined columns selected
[1] 4
```

And the error messages keep going for some time. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I have the same issue. The developer of this package has mentioned back in 2017 that it is not maintained anymore, and that the FAOSTAT API has changed, so I suspect we won't have much luck trying to figure it out, unfortunately! See https://github.com/mkao006/FAOSTATpackage#note-this-package-has-been-orphaned-due-to-the-current-re-development-of-the-faostat-api-and-the-fact-that-i-no-longer-work-for-the-organisation-and-has-no-access-to-the-updates